# Add two values to a database column?

Tags: php, database

Inside a custom metabox for wordpress, I need to get multiple meta values...

The Custom Meta Type:

```
case 'draggable':
   echo '<div id="'.$field['id'].'" class="daredevil"></div> 
         <input type="hidden" class="draggable-value" id="hidden" name="', $field['id'], '" value="', '' !== $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '"/>';
break;
```

Basically what im doing here is putting a draggable's top value inside the input's value field and then saving that to the database...

Here is how the row looks in the database, -443px is the top value...

[image]

I tried adding a new input for the left value but I suspect I cannot use `', '' !== $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '` twice, do I need a foreach statement or something?

Hope this was clear, in conclusion I just want to store top & left values, streamlining it is nice less code less tables is always ideal...

**UPDATE:** I added a foreach and this makes it easier to get the top & left values, but with the foreach I cannot add to the database, however when its just a single input I can add to the database..

```
case 'draggable':
                $i = 1;
                foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                  echo '<input type="hidden" class="draggable-value" id="hidden_'.$i.'" name="', $field['id'], '_'.$option['name'].'" value="', '' !== $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '"/>';                        
                  $i++;
                }
                echo '<div id="'.$field['id'].'" class="daredevil"></div> ';
            break;
```

I added some option values to my array TOP & LEFT...

```
array(
            'name' => 'Draggable Layers',
            'desc'    => 'Use the slider to set the height of the static area',
            'id' => $prefix . 'draggable_values',
            'type' => 'draggable',
            'options' => array(
                array( 'name' => 'top'),
                array( 'name' => 'left'),
            ),
        ),
```

And in the foreach it creates an input for each option, this is good for on/off values because the meta is slightly different, but I am still trying to figure out the best way to add both values to my DB table?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after fiddling around for hours, I figured it out..

There is a built in multiple function inside the metabox script..